# Remove "redundant" key frame

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have rigged body in blender with long animation. When I created the animation saved keys for all the bones in every frame, even though I did not move with them.

It can automatically delete the same keys? When I export the model and load it in a 3D engine I see that removed thousands of redundant keys and I wanted to remove it before export for smaller file and higher speed when loading.